# Реккурентная формула. Вычисление выражение

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, ряды

Дана формула, для вычисления функции S(x). Каким образом её вычислить.

[image: Формула]

Таким образом это сделал я, используя реккуретное соотношение, однако точность ответа неудовлетворенная.

```
long double s(long double x)
{
    long double sum, prev;

    sum = prev = pow(x,3.0) / 3.0; //start value

    for (int n = 2; n <= K; ++n) {
        prev *= -1.0 * (x * x);
        sum += prev / (4.0 * n * n - 1);
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Само полностью задание: вывести на экран таблицу функций y(x) и её разложение в ряд s(x) для x, изменяющегося от a=0.1 до b=1, c шагом h = 0.1. 
Функция y(x) дана.[image: y(x)]

Comment: "реккуретное" - где?

Comment: current = -prev * x * x;

Comment: "точность ответа неудовлетворенная." - это что значит?

Comment: Само полностью задание: вывести на экран таблицу функций y(x) и её разложение в ряд s(x) для x, изменяющегося от a=0.1 до b=1, c шагом h = 0.1. Функция y(x) дана.

Comment: "точность ответа неудовлетворенная." - что это значит?

Comment: значит, что значение y(x) не равно s(x) уже в 1 знаке после запятой. Например y(x) дает 0.29, а s(x)=0.31. Надо задать такой алгоритм, чтобы s(x) давала тоже ближе где-то к 0.29.

Comment: Предположим (только предположим!), что я захотел Вам помочь. Я могу воспроизвести явление, о котором Вы говорите?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66723/discussion-between-roman-alexandrovich-and-igor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
prev = pow(x,3.0); //start value
sum = prev / 3.0; //start value
```

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6ccnimsao9

Answer (score 1):

Ряд знакопеременный, можно смело указывать точность...

```
double s(double x, double eps = 1e-10)
{
    double a = x*x*x;
    x = x*x;
    double sum = a/3.0;
    for(int k = 2; fabs(a) >= 4*eps*k*k; ++k)
    {
        sum += (a*=-x)/(4.0*k*k-1);
    }
    return sum;
}



int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    for(double x = 0.1; x <= 1.0; x += 0.1)
    {
        cout << setw(4) << x << setw(12)
            << ((1+x*x)*atan(x)-x)/2.0
            << setw(12) << s(x) << endl;
    }
}
```

https://ideone.com/aWCFUH